# in_array vs strpos for performance in php

Tags: php, arrays, performance, strpos

I am logging in users via windows authentication and then storing that user's rights in a session variable.  I use a delimited method of rights storage in a database i.e:

```
$rights //retrieved from database 
= 'read,edit,delete,admin'
```

so my question is should I;

```
//generate variable
$_SESSION['userrights'] = $rights ($rights is retrieved from database)

//use strpos to find if right is allowed
if (strpos($_SESSION['userrights'],"admin") !== false) { // do the function }
```

OR

```
//make array of rights
$_SESSION['userrights'] = explode(',',$rights)

//use in_array to find if right is allowed
if (in_array("admin",$_SESSION['userrights'])) { // do the function }
```

Bit of a OCD question as I presume the difference will be pretty much negligible for what I am doing but which would be the faster (use less resources) method?

Any answers appreciated except ones that insult my method of rights storage!

Comment: Use the second method, for sure. Checking for a specific value in an array is a much better method compared to looking for a value inside a string. Note that `in_array` argument order is `needle,haystack`, not `haystack,needle` as you have there.

Comment: 2:50AM lazy copy and pasting! appreciate the answer!

Comment: Why don't you store them as the keys in an associative array? That should be faster than either.

Comment: You mean so I could use isset($_SESSION['admin']) instead?

Comment: Yeah, or `isset($_SESSION['userrights']['admin'])`

Comment: That's a pretty brilliant solution!
explode to $arr, and then `foreach($arr as $str) { $_SESSION['userrights'][$str] = 1 }` I presume would be the best method?

Comment: @DJB I like [this idea](http://discdev.com/2010/07/16/using-binary-numbers-for-permissions/) of [permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9811127/3110638). Nice [comparable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10504868/3110638) with [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strpos` is the fastest way to search a text needle, per [the php.net documentation for `strstr()`](https://www.php.net/strpos):

> If you only want to determine if a particular **needle** occurs within **haystack**, use the faster and less memory intensive function [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead.<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)</sup>

Answer (score 17):

As I often work with large datasets, I'd go with `isset` or `!empty` on an associative array and check for the key, like @Barmar suggests. Here is a quick 1M benchmark on an *Intel® Core™ i3-540 (3.06 GHz)*

```
$test = array("read", "edit", "delete", "admin");

echo "<pre>";

// --- strpos($rights,$test[$i%4]) ---

$rights = 'read,edit,delete,admin';
$mctime = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<=1000000; $i++) { if (strpos($rights,$test[$i%4]) !== false) { }}
echo '  strpos(... '.round(microtime(true)-$mctime,3)."s\n";

// --- in_array($test[$i%4],$rights) ---

$rights = array("read", "edit", "delete", "admin");
$mctime = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<=1000000; $i++) { if (in_array($test[$i%4],$rights)) { }}
echo 'in_array(... '.round(microtime(true)-$mctime,3)."s\n";

// --- !empty($rights[$test[$i%4]]) ---

$rights = array('read' => 1, 'edit' => 1, 'delete' => 1, 'admin' => 1);
$mctime = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<=1000000; $i++) { if (!empty($rights[$test[$i%4]])) { }}
echo '  !empty(... '.round(microtime(true)-$mctime,3)."s\n";

// --- isset($rights[$test[$i%4]]) ---

$rights = array('read' => 1, 'edit' => 1, 'delete' => 1, 'admin' => 1);
$mctime = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<=1000000; $i++) { if (isset($rights[$test[$i%4]])) { }}
echo '   isset(... '.round(microtime(true)-$mctime,3)."s\n\n";

echo "</pre>";
```

The winner is `isset`:

```
  strpos(... 0.393s
in_array(... 0.519s
  !empty(... 0.232s
   isset(... 0.209s
```

Comment: The performance characteristics come from using an associative array instead of a list. Although your benchmark is slightly flawed, you're not including any balance, and only testing worst case scenario of the `strpos` and `in_array` (last entry in the array/string). To make it fairer, you should use a modulo 4 on $i and fetch that from an array. However, associative arrays scale better and false results is also faster with them.

Comment: @Aidiakapi Thanks for your comment! Modified it a bit.

Comment: @Jonny5 Thank you for going to this amount of effort to appease my ocd! I am using isset due to yours and Barmar 's answers.. much appreciated

Comment: I might be missing something but does this test take into account the time it would take to convert from the csv in the database string to the array keys? or is that considered negligible?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to what Mike has asked above also!  If you have a text blob, would it be faster to explode it into an array and then use isset() over just using strpos() straight up on the text?

Answer (score 1):

A benchmark that proofs that `strpos` is not the fastest method, but faster than `in_array`:

```
<?php

echo phpversion() . PHP_EOL;

// build random array
$array = array_fill(0, 10000, 16);
$array = array_map('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes', $array);
$array = array_map('bin2hex', $array);
$array_flipped = array_flip($array);
$string = implode($array);
$random_keys = array_rand($array_flipped, 10);

$loops = 10000;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
    strpos($string, $random_keys[ rand(0, 9) ]);
}
echo __LINE__ . ': ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 5) . PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
    in_array($random_keys[ rand(0, 9) ], $array);
}
echo __LINE__ . ': ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 5) . PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
    isset($array_flipped[ $random_keys[ rand(0, 9) ] ]);
}
echo __LINE__ . ': ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 5) . PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
    $array_flipped = array_flip($array);
    isset($array_flipped[ $random_keys[ rand(0, 9) ] ]);
}
echo __LINE__ . ': ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 5) . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Result:

```
5.6.31
19: 1.11484
25: 1.3109
31: 0.00237
38: 13.64204
```

As you can see it is important not to flip an array on-the-fly to benefit from `isset`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered the possibility of doing a query on the database if `$_SESSION['userrights']` exists in the database? You're already doing a query to get the list of rights in your example, why not do a query for a specific `$_SESSION['userrights']` and check if there are any rows returned?

Comment: I was under the impression that querying would be far more intensive that either strpos or in_array.. I already query the database and store the value in a session var so I have the values to hand.

Unless I mis-understand, you are suggesting I query every time I want to check if user has a certain level of rights? (I have multiple things displaying based on whether user has one right or another)

Comment: How many times are you doing a user rights look-up on a page?

Comment: The application isn't finished yet, but I'm guessing the maximum right now would be 2/3