# if statement with multiple or condition

Tags: php, if-statement

Consider the following code

```
if (  stripos($a,'something1')===0 || stripos($a,'something2')===0  ) {
        return '';
}
```

Is there a performance benefit for using `in_array` or does php stops testing if first condition evaluate to true ?

Comment: Yes PHP does stop if the first one is true during the short circuit evaluation, which PHP has

Comment: @Rizier123 ...Thanks for reminding me of the term `short circuit evaluation`.Suppose that that i had like 3-7 more `stripos` in the condition , will there be any performance benefit in using in_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative to your question about performance.

As they say here, strpos is better.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070786/4627253